# Socket.io stops emitting when any of the window is minimized

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple real time text editor that can be accessed and edited by a couple of collaborators at the very same time (not using any lock properties for now). It all works well, transmits live data - until I minimize any of the window (basically using two chrome windows to see the results) and socket stops emitting data. 
Here are the server and client -

**Server**

```html
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(4000);
console.log("server running");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.sockets.on("connection", socket => {
  
  //Connect
  connections.push(socket);
  console.log("connected: ", connections.length);

  //Disconnect
  socket.on("disconnect", data => {
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log("disconnected! left:  ", connections.length);
  });


  //Send Message
  socket.on('send message', data => {
    console.log(data);
    io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: data});
  });
});
```

**Client**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Chat</title>

    <link
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="msgArea" id="msgArea">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div>
              <h3>RealTime Editor</h3>
              <ul class="list-groups" id="users"></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
  
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>
            <form action="" id="msg-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Enter below</label>
                <textarea name="" id="msg" rows="15" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <br />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
      console.log("connect");
      const socket = io.connect();
      let $msg = $("#msg");

      socket.on("new message", data => {
        // $chat.append('<div class="well">' + data.msg + "</div>");
        $('#msg').text(data.msg);
      });

      $("#msg").on("change keyup paste", function() {
        socket.emit("send message", $msg.val());
      });     
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This could be a performance decision by the OS, or the browser?

Comment: What do you mean "socket stops emitting data"?  Your client-side code doesn't show any emits that should happen when the window is minimized.  FYI, browsers these days will slow or stop timers from running when the window is not visible (though the code you show doesn't show any of those).  This is a battery saving maneuver.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem's with the server emitting the data or is it with the client capturing it. Bdw, server does recieve the data even when any window is minimized.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?  What exactly is not received?  You've not been specific at all.  The client code you show does not send anything when it's minimized so I have no idea what the actual problem is.  Please fix your question to be clear what exact problem you want help with.

Comment: The data is not being received at the client end, and "The client code you show does not send anything when it's minimized" - the client is not supposed send anything when minimized (unfocused), it needs to receive - and that's exactly what my problem is - client doesn't receive any data